# Insert Python dictionary into Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a dictionary that has the following shape:

```
{0: {'a': 'cat',
  'b': 'dog',
  'c': 'bus',
  'd': 'snake'},
{1: {'a': 'ddsdf',
  'b': 'sdfs',
  'c': 'asdfsd',
  'd': 'asdfds'},
}
```

```
placeholders = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(df_merge.columns))
columns = ', '.join(df_merge.columns)

df_merge_reset_index = df_merge.reset_index(drop=True)
merge_to_dict = df_merge_reset_index.to_dict('dict')
merge_to_dict_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(merge_to_dict, orient='index')
dict_ = merge_to_dict_df.to_dict('dict')

sql = """INSERT INTO test ({}) VALUES ({}) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;""" \
        .format(columns_, placeholders_)
```

Currently, I am using a for loop

```
for i in dict_.values():
    cursor.execute(sql,
                   (i['a'], i['b'], i['c'], i['d'])
                   )
```

But this is very slow, and I would like to use either `from psycopg2.extras import execute_values` or `from psycopg2.extras import execute_batch` but the way my dictionary is setup does not allow this. Would anyone have a recommendation on how to transform my data so I can use it with `execute_values` or `execute_batch`?

---- UPDATE:

I changed the structure to something thats a little closer by keeping it as a record.

```
df_merge_reset_index = df_merge_.reset_index(drop=True)
merge_to_dict = df_merge_reset_index.to_dict('records')
```

```
[{'a': '',
  'b': '',
  'c': ',
  'd': ''}]
```

`cursor.executemany(sql, merged_dict)`

I get the following error `cursor.executemany(sql, merged_dict) TypeError: dict is not a sequence`

Comment: Where did that dictionary come from? Indexing a dictionary by integers 0, 1, etc. is a sign that this is the wrong data structure in the first place. You might be looking for a list.

Comment: Also, that's not a valid `dict`. Please fix it, we can't be expected to guess at what your real data looks like.

Comment: Have you tried `executemany()`?

Comment: You mean in the for loop?

Comment: @Brandon, I'm pretty sure John means _instead of_ the for loop. See https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html?highlight=executemany#cursor.executemany

Comment: Yes; I've tried that. Here is my output:     
```cursor.executemany(sql, dict_)```
```TypeError: 'int' object does not support indexing```

Comment: If you are passing a list of dicts to `executemany()` then your placeholder needs to be `%(dict_key)s` or in your case: `%(a)s, %(b)s, ...`. See [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of rows you want to insert, do it in 2 steps instead of execute many and others. Even with execute many you'd have to be sending multiple queries when you can just be done in 2.

You can just load the entire df in a single query without worrying about the conflicts, and then you can just transfer it in another query.

Prerequisites:

1. Create an intermediate table for your actual table

Steps:

1. Turn df into a csv
2. `COPY` the csv to intermediate table with `cursor.copy_from(csv)`
3. insert into the actual table from the intermediate table

```sql
INSERT INTO actual (...)
SELECT ...
FROM intermediate
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```

https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html

Answer (score 0):

```
list_ = []
for i in merged_dict.values():
    list_.append((i['a'], i['b'], i['c'], i['d'], i['bid'],))
LOG.info("Execute many")
execute_values(cursor, insert_query, tuple_, template=None, page_size=100)
```

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved with some explanation.